# Passing a port number into an alias

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments, alias, port-number

I am trying to create an alias for the following command

`lsof -i :$1 | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill`

However I keep getting an error:

`lsof: unacceptable port specification in: -i :`

I tried different things but I keep failing to pass the port number successfully. How can I pass the port number into this alias?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to pass a parameter into a specific position, an alias cannot be done. Instead, create a function:

```
myfunc() {
   lsof -i :$1 | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill
}
```

If you save it in your `~/.bashrc` file you will be able to call it with `myfunc parameter`.

Comment: +1 This is what I had also typed but then noticed an alert and saw your similar answer.

Comment: So we kind of thing the same exactly way, @anubhava :))